# HTTP protocol version undefined in requests to my socket.io server?

Tags: javascript, http, websocket, socket.io, http-headers

I have a socket.io server setup on an AWS EC2 instance. I am able to connect fine, as are most people, but I'm running into an issue with a couple of users where the HTTP protocol version is undefined. I have supplied two requests to my socket io server, one with an expected HTTP version, and one where it is undefined. It seems that otherwise the requests are the same, which leads me to believe that the HTTP version is the problem.

GET Request that is working fine (removed specific ip/website info)

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Nit_A4F HTTP/1.1
Host: {{My EC2 Host:Port}}
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: {{My Website}}
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: {{My Website}}
```

GET Request that is failing **(Note line 1, where the HTTP version is undefined, rather than HTTP/1.1)**

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Nit_UGj undefined
Host: {{My EC2 Host:Port}}
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: {{My Website}}
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: {{My Website}}
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

There's a couple of questions in this problem, really. First, is the undefined HTTP protocol version a common or reasonable use case? If so, is there a way I can manually set the HTTP protocol version on the frontend (Angular), or set up CORS to handle the undefined HTTP protocol version on the backend?

If the undefined HTTP protocol version is not a reasonable use case, is there anything these users can do to fix it?

Here is my current socket.io setup on the backend with CORS:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    transports: [ 'websocket', 'polling' ],
    credentials: true,
  }
});
```

I don't have much on my frontend besides just connecting to the correct url, but here it is just in case:

```
export class SocketIOService {
  private socket: io.Socket;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(
      environment.socketUrl
    );
  }

  sendData(socketEvent: string, data: any) {
    this.socket.emit(socketEvent, data);
  }

  getData(socketEvent: string) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket.on(socketEvent, msg => {
        console.log("handling event");
        observer.next(msg);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: if HTTP version not defined, the default version is 0.9. Your server might not support that version. Are theses users using same clients ? or old technologies ?

Comment: @AntoninRiche There is a big difference between a request not sending an HTTP version at all (that IS how HTTP 0.9 works, but request headers don't exist in 0.9) versus sending an HTTP version number saying `undefined` (malformed request). The requests shown are NOT using HTTP 0.9, they are malformed requests, and any sane processor *should* reject them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer as to why this specific problem occurs, I can't say I have an answer.

The solution that was applicable to me to solve my issue was to upgrade my frontend and backend to communicate through https instead of http.

Comment: I have the same problem. However, sometimes happen and sometimes not. Do you think is like yours? Thanks,